# regarding backslash from postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

i have a noob question.

I have a record in a table that looks like '\1abc'

I then use this string as a regex replacement in `re.sub("([0-9])",thereplacement,"2")`

I'm a little confused with the backslashes. The string i got back was `"\\1abc"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using python interactivly?

In regular string you need to escape backslashes in your code, or use r"..." (Link to [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)). If you are running python interactivly and don't assign the results from your database to a variable, it'll be printed out using it's `__repr__()` method.

```
>>> s = "\\1abc"
>>> s
'\\1abc' # <-- How it's represented in Python code
>>> print s
\1abc # <-- The actual string
```

Also, your re.sub is a bit weird. 1) Maybe you meant [0-9] as the pattern? (Matching a single digit). The arguments are probably switche too, if `thereplacement` is your input. This is the syntax:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0)
```

So my guess is you expect something like this:

```
>>> s_in  = yourDbMagic() # Which returns \1abc
>>> s_out = re.sub("[0-9]", "2", s_in)
>>> print s_in, s_out
\1abc \2abc
```

**Edit:** Tried to better explain escaping/representation.

Comment: i have edited my sub string. a careless mistake there. Well, I'm trying to replace the "2" actually. Oh and I'm  not using python interactively.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can make \ stop being an escape character by setting standard_conforming_strings to on.

Comment: I agree: using standard_conforming_strings = on is the way to go. Btw: this is the default in 9.0 now.